# How to use prepod with Blockfrost api

Tags: wallet

Good evening,
I am working on a crypto wallet that deals with `cardano(ADA)`, and while testing i discovered that `blockfrost` api for testnet is deprecated, so i could not get testnet token to test, and later switched to prepod but i don't know how to connect `blockfrost` api with prepod test network, i tried reaching out to `blockfrost` but to no avail,please how can i use prepod with `blockfrost` api?
this is my cardano address addr_test1qrum7e26tfvdxgy3glpmrcsrsza4lpfqyqn0phklplm3wscunjd64pwwcfdsmdqrmxry5ma0smajh37vdp0jwzx82jpsheutwf
for legacy testnet.

Answer (score 1):

There are different urls for each network.
From the doc: https://docs.blockfrost.io

[image: https://docs.blockfrost.io]

Comment: please i am trying to use it with flutter
`
cardano_wallet_sdk: ^0.1.0-alpha.12
`